# How to join two data frames in R such that only records common to both are returned

Tags: r

I'm trying to join two data frames which have a date column. Not all the dates are in each data frame. How would you go about joining these two data farms?

I want to return a data frame where I only have data which is common to both data frames.

Test Data:

```
set.seed(12)
Date <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
var1<-sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 12, replace = TRUE)
df1<- data.frame(Date, var1)

set.seed(12)
Date <- seq(as.Date("2000/2/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
var2<-sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 2), size = 12, replace = TRUE)
df2<- data.frame(Date, var2)
```

I tired:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "Date", all = TRUE)

sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 INNER JOIN df2 ON df1.Date=df2.Date")
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want common to both (which is the default for `merge`), then don't use `all=TRUE`.

Comment: What is it that you want that the lines you tried don't give you al;ready?

Answer (score 2):

**Using base r:**

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "Date")

         Date var1 var2
1  2000-02-01   45   22
2  2000-03-01   50   46
3  2000-04-01   25   50
4  2000-05-01   25   28
5  2000-06-01   20   24
6  2000-07-01   25   20
7  2000-08-01   40   24
8  2000-09-01   20   40
9  2000-10-01   20   20
10 2000-11-01   30   20
11 2000-12-01   45   32
```

**Using dplyr:**

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1,df2)
```

Produces:

```
Joining by: "Date"
         Date var1 var2
1  2000-02-01   45   22
2  2000-03-01   50   46
3  2000-04-01   25   50
4  2000-05-01   25   28
5  2000-06-01   20   24
6  2000-07-01   25   20
7  2000-08-01   40   24
8  2000-09-01   20   40
9  2000-10-01   20   20
10 2000-11-01   30   20
11 2000-12-01   45   32
```